# Tab Bar with JSQMessageViewController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQmessageViewController and I have a Tab Bar in my Application. The Tab Bar hides the text field and makes it unusable. Anybody have a solution?

Comment: do you have a screen shot and could you provide the code you are using to present the MessageView?

Comment: I think the messageView presents itself @DanielLeonard

Comment: No like your tab bar logic 
        let tab1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: DialerViewController())
        let tab2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: RecentsTableViewController())


        tab1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "1", image:  UIImage(named: "dialPad"))
        tab2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "2", image: UIImage(named: "recent"))
        
        self.viewControllers = [tab1, tab2]
    }

Comment: The Message View is presented through a TableView which is one of the Tabs in the Tab Bar. There is a physical segue in each table view cell to show the MessageView.

Comment: have u solved that issue i m also facing same issue bro @RyanCocuzzo

Answer (score 0):

Set the `contentInset` for the view to the hight of your `tabBar`